# How can I upload a text file the best into a database as I want it to? (in C)

Tags: mysql, c, database, scanf, load-data-infile

At first what I need to do: I need to input a text file into a database.

That not very hard, but the text file they gave me is kinda strange.

I modified it so that it looks good in the Database, but they don't want to change every file by hand all the time. So I thought why am I not splitting the text file into separate text files or in arrays and upload those bit o where it should belong in the database.

But after searching a long time in the internet I couldn't find anything on how to do (or maybe I found something but I didn't get it :p).

So my question is:

What is the best way to split a text file so that i can upload the chunks in the database? Would it be the best to split it up in a lot of text files and upload every text file or do it in a array and upload those arrays into the database.

The text file it self is divided text and numbers and they only want the numbers to be uploaded into the database and the text in it are the column names of the database.

Here is an example of such a text file (normally without those spaces between it):

```
 UsindsVorigeCall =

 -1.0000;0.0000;0.0000;0.0000;

 WeerSindsVorigeCall =

 -1.0000;10.1000;7.5200;10.4000;

 0.0000;10.4000;7.6740;10.7000;

  KlimaatSindsVorigeCall =
 -1.0000;7.4000;8.8000;6.6000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;

 0.0000;7.4000;8.9000;6.7000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;-99.0000;

 KlimaatCompuSettings =

 8.0000
 21.0000
 0.0000
 0.0000
 -4.0000
 2.0000
 5.0000
 0.0000
 4.0000
 30.0000
 0.4000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
 -99.0000
```

If there is also an other option I would be open to it and try it out.

This is the output that I would like to have:http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30ue5pd&s=8 (this is with a self edited text file)

Comment: You need to work on your question, it's completely unclear.

Comment: I don't know why it's unclear to you. every number needs to be made into a seperate file so taht it can be uploaded in the database. So I need to do a programm which is putting the numbers from like "UsindsVorigeCall"in one file and the numbers of "WeerSindsVorigeCall"so that it can be uploaded into the database.

Comment: Then you are in serious trouble, since the file has no consistent format. In this case the "_quickest_" solution is to do it manually.

Comment: Unless you tell how the table(s) that you want to feed with the file are organized, and where each value from the file must go, we cannot help you. If you want help, it is not enough that the question can be understood by you, it must be understandable by other ;-) . Said differently, you have already shown the input, but what is the expected output ?

Comment: Mostly, you just need to say "this is the raw input I get" and "this is my desired output" AS EXAMPLES and then provide an attempt at coding your own solution so that we can help you fix the solution. SO doesn't provide free programming. We help you fix existing broken code.

Comment: This is the output that I want to have (this is with a self edited text file): http://i59.tinypic.com/30ue5pd.png

Answer (score 0):

Use the BLOB type instead of TEXT, it allows you to write whatever you want.

But I don't approve the fact of writing files in db, it's not made for that: these are relational databases, not garbage.

You should write files directly on filesystem, in a specific folder, and use the database to list the paths and store the data used for the research queries.

Comment: Not realy helpful since i don't want the words in the database only the nubers. (p.s. I wouldn't do it neither but they want me to do it. I would prefer save it in excel or some kind of stuff, but that's out of the question :x)